# Eclipse WTP: Programmatically start server: Could not load server adapter

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-wtp

Project is based on Eclipse Luna. I need to programmatically find all the server instances and start user selected server programmatically, just as what happens in WTP's Servers view. I use the following code snippet:

```
if (selectedServer.canStart(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE).isOK()) {
    // start server here
}
else {
    System.out.println("The server cannot be started: " + selectedServer.canStart(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE));
}
```

The selectedServer is the server instance that user selected from the UI. The problem is canStart() always fails with the following error message:

```
The server cannot be started: Status ERROR: org.eclipse.wst.server.core code=0 Could not load server adapter. Check to make sure that the installation is complete. null
```

I am sure the server adapters are installed on the testing IDE because I can start the server (in this case it is Tomcat 8.0) from that IDE successfully.

Anyone knows how to handle this? And any references would be a great help. Thanks.